# Date Picker Taking the Default DateTime( 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.) how can i take the selected date from the Calender

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-mvc-4

```
    <tr>
        <td>Dated:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtdate" name="Dated" value="" required />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

This is My Html TextBox For the DateProperty

```
function claimsubmit() { 
var claimtype;
if ($('.boxGroup a').attr("id") != '') {
     claimtype = $('.boxGroup a').attr("id");
}
var claimname = {
    //ClaimTypeId: $('.boxGroup a').attr("id"),
    ClaimTypeId:claimtype,
    BillNumber: $('#txtbillnum').val(),
    Amount: $('#txtamnt').val(),
    Reason: $('#txtreason').val(),
    Dated: $('#txtdate').val(),
    Id: $('#Id').val()
}
alert(JSON.stringify(claimname));
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/ClaimAPI', type: ($('#claimform').find('#Id').val() == '0' ? 'Post' : 'Put'),
    datatype: 'json',
    data: $.param(claimname),
    success: function (data) {
        //alert(data);
        alert("Claim Details are Submitted Successfully");
    },
    Error: function (data) {
        alert("Problem while Save Claim Details")
    }
});
}
```

This is javascript for insert and in controller am getting the default sqldate not selected date

[image: Here The date Value property is assigned with<code>![1]</code> initial value this is the problem]

Comment: Are you using jquery datepicker?

Comment: Yes AM using the Jquery date picker..

Comment: But i got the Problem actually what's the problem means my datatype is smalldatetime but when i pick up the date from the  Jquery datepicker nu its only getting the Date not time so thts why its taking the default date time..but one doubt some times its getting the selected date but sometimes its not getting the selected date  so here only i got confused so please help me.and how can i get the date as well time from the Jquerydatepicker this is my question...

Comment: please refer this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ you are not setting/getting the date from datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way of getting Date value from datepicker is to use getDate() function.

**getDate()**

Returns: Date Returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has been selected.

This method does not accept any arguments.

**Code examples:**

Invoke the getDate method:

```
var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
```

**setDate( date )**

Sets the date for the datepicker. The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date format (e.g., "01/26/2009"), a number of days from today (e.g., +7) or a string of values and periods ("y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, "d" for days, e.g., "+1m +7d"), or null to clear the selected date.

```
date
Type: String or Date
The new date.
```

**Code examples:**

Invoke the setDate method:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

You can find more details at [Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)